# "Bread" mean in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

A-How would you like to chop wood for me ?”

B-“I wouldn’t refuse to do that, but in these days even skilled wood-cutters find
themselves **sitting without bread**.”

**Bread** means i think -money

Comment: Where did you get this text from? I suspect it wasn't from a native Anglophone.

Comment: ...I now see it's a poor translation of Chekov's original Russian text of [*The Beggar*.](https://www.edumple.com/cbse-class-9/english/chapter-10-the-beggar/notes) Almost all references to it are from non-native-Anglophone TEFL resources.

Answer (score 1):

Money, but more specifically, the money with which you "put bread on the table" — an expression meaning to earn enough to pay for your basic needs.

Answer (score 1):

It might mean money, or it might mean the food.  It is hard to tell without more context.

The specific context is that this is from a story by Anton Chekhov, and wasn't written in English. You are only reading a translation.

The original text is

> — Я не отказываюсь, но нынче и настоящие дровоколы сидят без хлеба.

You should take this to [Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com) and ask if "хлеба" should be understood literally (as the food) or metaphorically (as livelihood)

According to Russian Wiktionary, it can have this figurative meaning in Russian.

> *перен., обобщ., неисч. пропитание, пища, средства к существованию ◆ Зарабатывать себе на хлеб.*